# iOS apps authentication and API

Tags: ios, authentication

I am pretty much newbie in iOS app developments. I have a question about authentication from iOS app.

Consider Android where a Google account is mandatory for each device and using the same account we can authenticate in any Android application.

Is there any similar approach available in iOS? May be using that we can authenticate user directly into iPhone application?

Comment: You can use your google account in iOS. It has a different API which is in Swift/Objective-C. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating

Comment: Thanks @codebot for commenting. I want iPhone users to have the ability to login to Apple account using one click just the way Android users can login using Google. Is there any way?

Comment: @Downvoters - if you can care to add some comments also please.

Comment: Apple does not provide a mechanism to allow 3rd parties to authenticate users via their Apple ID.

Comment: So @Paulw11 there is no way to login using iPhone app like say "Sign in with Apple or iTunes account" just like Android apps can sign in with Google?

Comment: No.  I am pretty sure Apple would see privacy concerns in allowing 3rd party apps access to Apple ID information.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides iCloud features for authentication purposes. It lets you save data and files in iCloud storage and it will be synced between all devices logged in with the same iCloud account.

If you want to keep using your Google accounts on iOS devices as well there is no native way of doing so. However there are several libraries and pods available for this purpose. Google has a good SDK for working with Google Authentication and it is well documented as well.

> https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating